# SecurePay Direct Post url Redirection

Tags: php

I am integrating secure pay direct post with my website. 
Below is the form I have used in the main (index.php) page. 
The form requires many different parameters to be passed as HIDDEN fields as shown below.

One of the hidden field used is 'EPS_RESULTURL' where the result is redirect to after both APPROVED or DECLINED transactions.

```
Index.php

<form name="input" action="https://api.securepay.com.au/test/directpost/authorise"      method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_MERCHANT" value="<?php echo $EPS_MERCHANTID;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_TXNTYPE" value="<?php echo $EPS_TXNTYPE;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_REFERENCEID" value="<?php echo $EPS_REFERENCEID;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_AMOUNT" value="<?php echo $EPS_AMOUNT;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_TIMESTAMP" value="<?php echo $EPS_TIMESTAMP;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_FINGERPRINT" value="<?php echo $fingerprint;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_RESULTURL"  value="http:://www.mydomain.com/result.php"/>

<input type="text" name="EPS_CARDNUMBER" id="EPS_CARDNUMBER" placeholder="card number" class="cardnumber"/>
<input type="text" name="EPS_EXPIRYMONTH" id="EPS_EXPIRYMONTH" placeholder="mm" class="month"/>
<input type="text" name="EPS_EXPIRYYEAR" id="EPS_EXPIRYYEAR" placeholder="yyyy" class="year"/>
<input type="text" name="EPS_CCV" id="EPS_CCV" placeholder="cvv"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submitBtn">
</form>

result.php
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

**For Approved Transaction:**

The URL is redirected to result.php and hence prints the POST data received from the server. However, in the browser the URL is still

*https://api.securepay.com.au/test/directpost/authorise.*

I wish somehow I could stay in my own site ***www.mydomain.com*** instead of redirecting to 
*https://api.securepay.com.au/test/directpost/authorise*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but for anyone want to avoid this , SecurePay now has `EPS_REDIRECT` to change this behaviour

```
<input type="hidden" name="EPS_REDIRECT" value="TRUE"/>
```

will move to your page , with result parameters as a `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Change `result.php` to:

```
<?php
header("location:yoururl.php");
exit();
?>
```

And it will redirect you where you want to be. Generally speaking, `results.php` is where you want to pick that `$_POST` data, parse it and do something with it, redirecting the user afterwards. Even more generally speaking, `results.php` is where you will do some magic and shoot the user over to `thanksforpaying.php`.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thank you for your reply. I have used redirect in the similar way you have mentioned here. It does the actual redirection, but my question is Why doesn't the URL change in the browser to the redirected URL. in our case "http:://www.mydomain.com/yoururl.php".

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I wasn't aware that you tried this one. I'm not sure, I have experience with different provider, and what they had was 3 urls. 1 for payment data, 1 for success and 1 for fail. So they would send you payment data to one url, and redirect you to success/fail ones. Maybe it's missing from the form, sorry that I didn't answer you correct.

Comment: You also may want to check this out: http://test.web.securepay.com.au/resources/eSec/SSL-Browser-Redirect-Integration-Guide-pg07.html

I haven't used the method so I'm unsure, but seems good?

Comment: Thanks Sam. Will test a combination of these and let you know. Cheers.

Comment: Anytime man, hope it works. Make sure to post the correct stuff it it does! =)